# How do I create an Enum from an interger value

Tags: scala

My application has the following `Enum`.

```
object UserTokenType extends Enumeration {
  type TokenType = Value
  val RegistrationConfirmation = Value("RegistrationConfirmation")
  val ResetPasswordConfirmation = Value("ResetPasswordConfirmation")
}
```

I store the value of the enum in the database by using the `id` of the `Enum`. When I read the value from the database, I want to recreate the `Enum` so that I can pass it around in my data model. At the moment, I have done it as follows

```
val userTokenType:UserTokenType.TokenType = if(row.getInt("is_sign_up") == UserTokenType.RegistrationConfirmation.id) {
      UserTokenType.RegistrationConfirmation
    }else{
      UserTokenType.ResetPasswordConfirmation
    }
```

Is above the right way of converting an `Int` into an `Enum`?

Comment: `object X extends Enumeration { val A, B = Value }; X(0)`. Nobody uses Enumeration any more.

Comment: Thanks. If so, what is the equivalent of Enum? I generally find them more useful compared to   using integer literals.

Comment: Me too, that is their best use case. Advice on scala 2 is to prefer java enum or sealed trait with case object children. scala 3 has proper enum support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @som-snytt mentioned in the comment, you can use [apply(x:Int)](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Enumeration.html#apply(x:Int) :Enumeration.this.Value) to construct enum:

```
row.getInt("is_sign_up") match {
  case id if id >= 0 && id < UserTokenType.maxId => Some(UserTokenType(id))
  case _ => None
}
```

Comment: A lazy person might `Try(UTT(id)).toOption`.